# Error finding a column in a MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sqlexception, tablecolumn

I am trying to get a column from a table in my database, but I get the following error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'price' not found.
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1064)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDouble(ResultSetImpl.java:2234)
>       at webServices.TheServicesImplementation.findShops(TheServicesImplementation.java:964)
>       at main.MainFunction.main(MainFunction.java:26)

The query I use is :

```
private final String priceSQL = "select price as price from items_shops i where i.shop_id = ? and i.item_id = ?";
```

and my code is :

```
try {

    preparedStatementB = dbConnection.prepareStatement(priceSQL);
    preparedStatementB.setInt(1, shop_id);
    preparedStatementB.setInt(2, item_id);
    setB = preparedStatementB.executeQuery();
    if (!setB.next()) {
        System.out.println("Error finding price.");
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        price = set.getDouble("price");
    }
}catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();        
}finally{
    try {
        preparedStatementB.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this is weird, as a column `price` ***does*** exist in the table `items_shops` (executing the query in the SQL console succeeds). Could anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try executing this query from mysql console?

Comment: Yes, and it succeeds... :/

Comment: Are you sure your schema definition in connection settings are correct? Can you get another column from same table?

Comment: @Nambari I can get all the columns. I have got them in other queries I used. I cannot figure out what is wrong with this one. `Are you sure your schema definition in connection settings are correct?` what do you mean with that? Could you explain?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database in which you try (with success) to execute the query via mysql console?

Comment: For its worth, the fact that you can run your query in MySQL is irrelevant. The Java driver was also able to run it. The error is thrown when retrieving the value of 'price' from the ResultSet. Have you tried without the alias? Also, fully qualifying the column names (backticks and all)?

Comment: @Deroude "
For its worth, the fact that you can run your query in MySQL is irrelevant" I think this to make sure there is really a column named "price" exists, so this is worth to test. Other than that, I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resultset is assigned to a variable called `setB` but you're trying to extract the price from a variable called `set`.

Comment: Nice catch. If it is not a typo in question, this could be the problem.

Comment: Not if the code happens to declare a variable with that name of the right type.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I kept scanning all my code for any typos, but I just could not see it! Thanks a lot!